# Is it possible for PhpStorm to run Karma automatically on file changes?

Tags: phpstorm, karma-runner

To clarify, I know there are other file watchers e.g. grunt - which could watch for file changes, then launch Karma from the command line.
What I would like know is how to fire **Phpstorm's** "run configuration" for Karma on file changes, as it launches in its own tray, has a gui allowing you to click on a test and be taken to the test code etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try enabling 'Toggle Auto-test' button in testing results window toolbar.

Comment: thanks, I should have seen it, but thats exactly what I was looking for !